# Plotting animation time

Tags: python, python-3.x, animation, matplotlib, plot

I am plotting an animation and I want to see at which time/step the animation is while watching it.

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

cax1 = ax1.matshow(coherence_matrices[0], cmap='YlOrRd')
time = ax1.annotate(0, xy=(1, 8), xytext=(1, 8))

def animate(i):

    cax1.set_array(coherence_matrices[i])

    time.set_text(i)

    return time, cax1

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate,
                               frames=int((4000-window_size)/window_step), interval=80, blit=True)

plt.show()
```

I only came up with this solution, which should make appear the iteration number on top of the histogram, but nothing appears. I would like to know what is wrong and whereas there is a simpler way to see the timer in the animation.

Thanks a lot in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you have made sure that the coordinates of `annotate` are not actually outside the figure, which could also be an explanation for the text not showing up.

The problem appears with blitting turned on. There are two possibilities resulting in the same effect of not showing the text:
1. If the text is inside the axes, it will be hidden by the matshow object.
2. If the text is outside the axes, it will not be shown at all.

Now there are two solutions to this.

#### (a) don't use blitting.

Simply turn blitting off :

```
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, ...., blit=False)
```

#### (b) use another axes.

In case you really need to use blitting (because the animation gets too slow otherwise) you could use another axes to place the text label in.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

coherence_matrices = np.random.rand(80,3,3)

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
# add another axes at the top left corner of the figure
axtext = fig.add_axes([0.0,0.95,0.1,0.05])
# turn the axis labels/spines/ticks off
axtext.axis("off")

cax1 = ax1.matshow(coherence_matrices[0], cmap='YlOrRd')
# place the text to the other axes
time = axtext.text(0.5,0.5, str(0), ha="left", va="top")


def animate(i):
    cax1.set_array(coherence_matrices[i])

    time.set_text(str(i))

    return cax1, time,

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=len(coherence_matrices),
                                    interval=80, blit=True)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! In the end I plot the timer in another window, as you say.